# Drools Activation Group looping

Tags: drools

In my scenario I have two excel spread sheets (sheet1 and sheet2) which hold two separate decision tables.
In sheet1, the the rule looks like:

```
PRIORITY 0
NO-LOOP TRUE
ACTIVATION-GROUP Group1
AGENDA-GROUP Agenda1

    a  b | d
    1  2 | 1
```

So, if a == 1 and b == 2, set d to 1 
The command to set d is: `modify(input) {setD(1)}`

Sheet2 looks like the following:

```
PRIORITY 5
NO-LOOP TRUE
ACTIVATION-GROUP Group1
AGENDA-GROUP Agenda1

    a  c | d
    1  3 | 1
```

Both files have the same ACTIVATION-GROUP (activation1) and the same AGENDA-GROUP (agenda1)

I use the input of:

```
a  b  c  d
1  2  3  -2
```

I expect an activation to be created for each of the two rules. The rule with the higher priority will fire, and then because it is in an activation group, the second rule will be cancelled.

However, when I run, the rule in Sheet1 will get activated and run, and then the rule in Sheet2 will get activated and run, and this will loop infinitely.

To get an idea, here is a portion of the log output generated by the session:

```
==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15010_16 active=false ] 
==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ RuleId15010_16 active=false ]
==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15010_16 active=false ] 
==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15011_16 active=false ] 
==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ RuleId15011_16 active=false ] 
==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15011_16 active=false ] 
==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15010_16 active=false ] 
==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ RuleId15010_16 active=false ]
==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15010_16 active=false ] 
==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15011_16 active=false ] 
==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ RuleId15011_16 active=false ] 
==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15011_16 active=false ] 
==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15010_16 active=false ] 
==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ RuleId15010_16 active=false ] 
==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15010_16 active=false ] 
==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15011_16 active=false ] 
==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ RuleId15011_16 active=false ] 
==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ RuleId15011_16 active=false ]
```

I have already broken the rules into two seperate AGENDA-GROUPs, which is a solution, but I would like to know why the activate-group is not doing what I thought it should do.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is looping infinitely?

Answer (score 0):

Both rules are activated since all constraints evaluate to true. The a-c-d rule has the higher salience and so it'll fire. The activation of the a-b-d rule is indeed cancelled as it is in the same activation.

Now you update d using modify which instructs the engine to re-evaluate the modified fact, and so you are back to square 1, i.e., both rules are activated, the one with the higher salience is fired and ...

To break this vicious circle, write rule that describe the logic more accurately. Three ways:

(1) Use only one rule to set d=1. I provide the DRL:

```
rule abcd
when
  $inp: Input( a == 1, b == 2 || c == 3 )
then
  modify( $inp ){ setD(1) }
end
```

(2) Add a constraint on d to both rules:

```
rule abd
when
  $inp: Input( a == 1, b == 2, d != 1 )
then
  modify( $inp ){ setD(1) }
end
```

Adding a constraint on d might be a good idea even with my first proposal since there might be other rules setting e, f,... of Input.

(3) If you don't need Input.d in any of your rules, you can do a "dirty update", i.e.,

```
rule abd
when
  $inp: Input( a == 1, b == 2 )
then
  $inp.setD(1);
end
```

Most likely #2 is best suited for your spreadsheet approach.